# adodb.recordset worked in IIS6 but not in IIS7

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, iis-7, iis-6, adodb

Well, I moved an app (classic ASP) from a IIS 6 server to a IIS 7 server and now in trouble. I've tried very har to solve it, but no.

When i try to run it i get: error '80004005'

/main.asp, line 251

Line 251 is the "RS.Open SQL,cnpath" in the bit of code below.

```
cnpath="driver={SQL Server}; server=myserver; database=recept; Trusted connection=no; user id=weblogin; pwd=*****;"

' Create and open ADO recordset
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.CursorLocation = 3 ' adUseClient
RS.Open SQL,cnpath

If RS.EOF Then
    RS.Close
    set rs=nothing
' Clean up
'Do the no results HTML here
%><P style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: x-small; Font-Weight: bold; color: #000000;"><%
   Response.Write "Didn't find it."
%> </P><%
    Response.end
' Done
End If
```

It works perfectly on the IIS6 machine.

The above code is of course just a tiny bit of the application.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

//Tarzzz

Comment: You seem to be having problems connecting to the database.  There are loads of things which could cause this but it might be worth trying an OLEDB connection string, eg `"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=yourServer;Initial Catalog=yourDatabase;
User Id=yourUsername;Password=yourPassword;"`  Other connection strings can be found here. https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Thanks for answering John. Tried your suggestion above but now get: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005' 

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. 

/main.asp, line 251. Iäll check out the other connectionstrings.

Comment: A little more info. The asp-application is running on a Server 2008 and trying to connect to another machine running SQL Server 2005. I now tried: cnpath="Provider=SQLNCLI; Server=IPnr; Database=recept; Uid=weblogin; Pwd=****;" Then I get: ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e7a' 

Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. 

/main.asp, line 251

Comment: SQLOLEDB is installed on Windows servers by default, but the Native Client provider is not, it comes with SQL Server itself, so if you're connecting to a database on another machine SQLOLEDB is the one to use, unless you are able to install the native client driver yourself.  "SQL Server does not exist or access denied" means that either your webserver is not allowing outgoing connections or your database server is not accepting incoming ones, or both.  I've added a SQL Server tag to your question - I think your ASP will be fine once you've configured SQL Server correctly.

Comment: Here is some steps to fix connecton issues: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e03993c0-a5f5-40c1-8124-c99b7866b933/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: Can you use the ping command, or try browsing to the SQL server, just to see if the SQL server is reachable from the IIS7 machine?